# Master Page getting Could Not Load Type error when publishing

Tags: asp.net, publishing, master-pages

Everything works find locally, but when I publish my asp.net application to a remote server I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

    Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'JournalPages.MasterMain'.

    Source Error: 

    Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.master.cs" Inherits="JournalPages.MasterMain" %>
    Line 2:  
    Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

Source File: /journalpages/Main.Master    Line: 1
```

This happens on any page with a master page. I used Reflector to look at the assembly in the bin directory and the types are all there. Any ideas??

Comment: Is .net 2.0 definitely installed on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok it turns out they hadn't set up the site folder in IIS to be an Application. Once they did all worked well.

Comment: How exactly do you change it to be an Application instead of a Web Site? I have this exact same problem using II6 with a Web Application project.

Comment: Mine was solved by editing the <SourceWebPhysicalPath> in the web deployment project. It needs to be a relative path not one that points to your local machine.

Comment: In IIS, they just needed to set the ApplicationName.

Answer (score 2):

If you are generating a web setup and trying to test it by making installation then make sure that output files such as (Ui dll and its supporting dlls) are available in the BIN folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Just copy 'JournalPages.MasterMain.ca' and '**JournalPages.MasterMain.designer.cs**' in you virtual folder, fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to exchange `~/` by `.\`

example :

```
wrong :MasterPageFile="~/CMaster.master"
right :MasterPageFile=".\CMaster.master"
```

Comment: I misread this and changed my MasterPage.Master from
`CodeBehind="~\MasterPage.Master.vb"`
to
`CodeBehind=".\MasterPage.Master.vb"`
and it worked for my case. I didn't have to change MasterPageFile on any other pages. Weird.

Comment: Some pages using the master page work fine without further changes, but others are now failing. I think it's a compiler bug.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the web site in IIS is set to use .NET 1.1.  Go to the properties page of the web site in IIS, then click on the ASP.NET tab.  My bet is that the version says 1.1.4322

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  Only to find from comparing older sites I had built with earlier version of VS....
VS now uses "CodeBehind" in place of "CodeFile"...so I just search and replaced all the "CodeBehind" with "CodeFile" and poof it worked

(This is on GoDaddy)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem occured when I renamed masterpage. To solve I have to correct inherits in the Masterpage

```
Inherits="Namespace.MasterpaseClassName"
```