# Could not load type 'Pages_MasterPage'

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, publish

I performed a "WebSite Publish" and the following error occured:

> Could not load type 'Pages_MasterPage'.

I've searched the web and found that Post:
[Master Page getting Could Not Load Type error when publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709831/master-page-getting-could-not-load-type-error-when-publishing)

I am posting my question after making sure that the site folder is set up to be an application, therefore, the post didn't help me much.

The server I'm publishing on is 3.5 environment

[image: Here's the ERROR screen I'm getting:]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am new to this and don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Is not find the class of the page, and I do not see the `CodeFile` so this is probably missing

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
   CodeFile="Pages_MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="Pages_MasterPage" %>
```

and make sure the `Pages_MasterPage.master.cs` exist - if not maybe you need to recreate this master page and not change or make manual the header and the files.

Comment: The `CodeFile` is there alright: `<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs"  Inherits="Pages_MasterPage" %>`.
And the `MasterPage.master.cs` exists indeed.
Any more ideas? (I am beginning to suspect that I did something wrong with the IIS configurations perhaps.

Comment: Ok, so how to check that? Basically, I decided to run my website localy (not on the server) to test it, so I entered Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> IIS, then I selected my website and clicked on the `browse` (on the right side of the window) and then I've encoutered the following message: `The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map`
I don't know if that helps, just giving all the facts..

Comment: @Yanker You did not configure the asp.net with the iis. Its a complicate setup with many steps, so search on the google with your error message to find a full tutorial abut.

Comment: Actually, I entered went to Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features, clicked on `turn windows features on and off`, then opened IIS -> WWW services -> Applicattion development Features and selected `.Net Extensibility` , `ASP.NET` , `ASAPI` (both of them - extensions and features) **and it then did the job and loaded the website as I described above**